# update to php version in macbook

Tags: php, macos, apache, macos-sierra

I have started using MacBookPro9,2 for the first time and trying to ready my development environment it has installed `php 5.6.30` but I need latest `php 7.1` or `7.2`. So I ran `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.2` in terminal and then `sudo pico /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and checked this line `#LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so` which is already commented. then ran this `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` . close the terminal and reopen it and type `php -v` but it is showing the old **php 5.6.30** !!!

OS version 10.12.6 (16G29)

I am trying for last two days to just update php version as all my laravel projects are in php 7. Now I am very much frustrated Please help me.

Comment: also, i would give you the following advice : stick to homebrew for most (if not all) changes to your shipped osx.  You may eventually need to add modules to your php, that is where the homebrew advantage will definitely come. Also, i ended up nuking the shipped apache too (with homebrew), so i could easily modify the running php (i have multiple versions brewed in).

Comment: hmmm ... i dont know too much about Siera (refraining for the longest time possible, cuz apple is sure to trash my dev configuration. However, try adding `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` in your .bash_profile , close the terminal, reopen a new one, and check the version.

Answer (score 0):

Use Homebrew:

I would probably recommend you installing homebrew to manage such installations for you. With that installed you can just run the following command to install php7.1

```
brew update
brew install php71
```